# gridviev filter which filters by two different tables

Tags: filter, devexpress

My `gridview` is based on a two-tables relation - table A with Column Size (int) and table B with column Human with values (man, woman). Can I create filter which filters A.Size = "100" and B.Human = "man" and I want this filter when i choose `sourse` for my view to be A - when I sort not to see records which in table B have value "woman" and when I select B for view `sourse` when i filter - not to see records which in A have values different from "100". Can I create such a filter and how? If yes - what would be the appropriate representation of this filter  visual between `devExpress`'s components? Can I do it with direct filter from my grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, your GridControl is bound to a datasource containing two tables.  Since a filter is applied to a GridView and each GridView can only be bound to a single table, this filter condition cannot be applied to a GridView.  So, there are two solutions for you.  First, which I consider to be the best, is to apply this filter to the grid's underlying DataSource.
Second is the solution based on GridView's filtration.  In this case, you should apply a separate filter on both master and detail GridView objects.  I.e. the master gridView should have the following filter condition:

```
gridView1.ActiveFilterCriteria = new BinaryOperator("Size", 100);
```

To apply a filter condition to the detail GridView, handle the master GridView's MasterRowExpanded event to obtain the detail GridView object and apply a filter condition:

```
private void gridView1_MasterRowExpanded(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.CustomMasterRowEventArgs e) {
    GridView detailGridView = (sender as GridView).GetDetailView(e.RowHandle, e.RelationIndex);
    detailGridView.ActiveFilterCriteria = new BinaryOperator("Human", "man");
}
```

**NOTE**: the first solution is the best one.